# Camel : Unable to Catch an Exception in Netty4

Tags: exception, apache-camel, netty

I have a Netty4 interface that accepts a message and puts this message in a queue (ActiveMQ), if the connection to the queue is down while camel is running then there is an exception happening in Netty after receiving the caller's message that I can't catch in any OnException and any ErrorHandler, I tried using LoadBalance and failover but still the same issue, the problem in this case is the caller is waiting until timeout and even if the connection to the queue is restored, Camel is losing the caller's message and not continuing the route ( which is the worst issue).

My Routes :

```
            <route id="GetHl7Request">
                    <from uri="hl7listener" />
                    <transacted />
                    <multicast>
                            <to uri="direct:SaveRequestInMQChannel" />
                            <to uri="direct:AckToOrderSrcChannel" />
                    </multicast>
            </route>

            <route id="SendRequestToMQ">
                    <from uri="direct:SaveRequestInMQChannel" />
                    <inOnly uri="inboundMQ" />
                    <log logName="{{camel.general.info.logname}}" loggingLevel="INFO" 
                            message="HL7 Request from OrderSrc has been Saved to MQ" />
            </route>

            <route id="AckToOrderSrcHL7Request">
                    <from uri="direct:AckToOrderSrcChannel" />
                    <to uri="bean:HL7Processor?method=sendAckToOrderSrc" />
            </route>
```

Stack Trace :

```
[ #43 - NettyEventExecutorGroup] TransactionErrorHandler        WARN  Transaction rollback (0x5fa9247b) redelivered(unknown) for (MessageId: ID-Mohammadt-460-58269-1490636081104-0-1 on ExchangeId: ID-Mohammadt-460-58269-1490636081104-0-2) caught: Could not create JMS transaction; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Error while attempting to add new Connection to the pool
[ead #42 - NettyServerTCPWorker] NettyConsumer                  ERROR Caused by: [org.apache.camel.CamelExchangeException - Cannot write response to /127.0.0.1:58397. Exchange[ID-Mohammadt-460-58269-1490636081104-0-2]. Caused by: [io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException - org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not create JMS transaction; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Error while attempting to add new Connection to the pool]]
org.apache.camel.CamelExchangeException: Cannot write response to /127.0.0.1:58397. Exchange[ID-Mohammadt-460-58269-1490636081104-0-2]. Caused by: [io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException - org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not create JMS transaction; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Error while attempting to add new Connection to the pool]
    at org.apache.camel.component.netty4.handlers.ServerResponseFutureListener.operationComplete(ServerResponseFutureListener.java:54) [camel-netty4-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.netty4.handlers.ServerResponseFutureListener.operationComplete(ServerResponseFutureListener.java:36) [camel-netty4-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:507) [netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:481) [netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:420) [netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:122) [netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.PromiseNotificationUtil.tryFailure(PromiseNotificationUtil.java:64) [netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.notifyOutboundHandlerException(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:837) [netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:741) [netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:731) [netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1900(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:38) [netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1090) [netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1137) [netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1079) [netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) [netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403) [netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:445) [netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) [netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not create JMS transaction; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Error while attempting to add new Connection to the pool
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToByteEncoder.write(MessageToByteEncoder.java:125) ~[netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:739) ~[netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not create JMS transaction; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Error while attempting to add new Connection to the pool
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager.doBegin(JmsTransactionManager.java:216) ~[spring-jms-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.doInTransactionTemplate(TransactionErrorHandler.java:176) ~[camel-spring-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.processInTransaction(TransactionErrorHandler.java:136) ~[camel-spring-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:105) ~[camel-spring-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:114) ~[camel-spring-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197) ~[camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197) ~[camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.netty4.handlers.ServerChannelHandler.processAsynchronously(ServerChannelHandler.java:138) ~[camel-netty4-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.netty4.handlers.ServerChannelHandler.channelRead0(ServerChannelHandler.java:109) ~[camel-netty4-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105) ~[netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) ~[netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$600(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:38) ~[netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$7.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:354) ~[netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor.run(DefaultEventExecutor.java:66) ~[netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    ... 2 more
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Error while attempting to add new Connection to the pool
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createJmsException(PooledConnectionFactory.java:266) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createConnection(PooledConnectionFactory.java:225) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createConnection(PooledConnectionFactory.java:204) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager.createConnection(JmsTransactionManager.java:288) ~[spring-jms-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager.doBegin(JmsTransactionManager.java:186) ~[spring-jms-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.doInTransactionTemplate(TransactionErrorHandler.java:176) ~[camel-spring-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.processInTransaction(TransactionErrorHandler.java:136) ~[camel-spring-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:105) ~[camel-spring-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:114) ~[camel-spring-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197) ~[camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197) ~[camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.netty4.handlers.ServerChannelHandler.processAsynchronously(ServerChannelHandler.java:138) ~[camel-netty4-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.netty4.handlers.ServerChannelHandler.channelRead0(ServerChannelHandler.java:109) ~[camel-netty4-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105) ~[netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) ~[netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$600(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:38) ~[netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$7.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:354) ~[netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor.run(DefaultEventExecutor.java:66) ~[netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    ... 2 more
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:36) ~[activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:374) ~[activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:304) ~[activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:244) ~[activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createConnection(PooledConnectionFactory.java:275) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory$1.makeObject(PooledConnectionFactory.java:95) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory$1.makeObject(PooledConnectionFactory.java:92) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.create(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1041) ~[commons-pool2-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.addObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1221) ~[commons-pool2-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createConnection(PooledConnectionFactory.java:221) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createConnection(PooledConnectionFactory.java:204) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager.createConnection(JmsTransactionManager.java:288) ~[spring-jms-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager.doBegin(JmsTransactionManager.java:186) ~[spring-jms-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.doInTransactionTemplate(TransactionErrorHandler.java:176) ~[camel-spring-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.processInTransaction(TransactionErrorHandler.java:136) ~[camel-spring-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:105) ~[camel-spring-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:114) ~[camel-spring-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197) ~[camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197) ~[camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.netty4.handlers.ServerChannelHandler.processAsynchronously(ServerChannelHandler.java:138) ~[camel-netty4-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.netty4.handlers.ServerChannelHandler.channelRead0(ServerChannelHandler.java:109) ~[camel-netty4-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105) ~[netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) ~[netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$600(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:38) ~[netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$7.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:354) ~[netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor.run(DefaultEventExecutor.java:66) ~[netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.connect(TcpTransport.java:525) ~[activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doStart(TcpTransport.java:488) ~[activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.util.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:55) ~[activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.start(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:169) ~[activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityMonitor.start(InactivityMonitor.java:52) ~[activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:64) ~[activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.start(WireFormatNegotiator.java:72) ~[activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:64) ~[activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:64) ~[activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:354) ~[activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:304) ~[activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:244) ~[activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createConnection(PooledConnectionFactory.java:275) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory$1.makeObject(PooledConnectionFactory.java:95) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory$1.makeObject(PooledConnectionFactory.java:92) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.create(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1041) ~[commons-pool2-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.addObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1221) ~[commons-pool2-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createConnection(PooledConnectionFactory.java:221) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createConnection(PooledConnectionFactory.java:204) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager.createConnection(JmsTransactionManager.java:288) ~[spring-jms-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager.doBegin(JmsTransactionManager.java:186) ~[spring-jms-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.doInTransactionTemplate(TransactionErrorHandler.java:176) ~[camel-spring-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.processInTransaction(TransactionErrorHandler.java:136) ~[camel-spring-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:105) ~[camel-spring-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:114) ~[camel-spring-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197) ~[camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197) ~[camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.netty4.handlers.ServerChannelHandler.processAsynchronously(ServerChannelHandler.java:138) ~[camel-netty4-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.netty4.handlers.ServerChannelHandler.channelRead0(ServerChannelHandler.java:109) ~[camel-netty4-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105) ~[netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) ~[netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$600(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:38) ~[netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$7.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:354) ~[netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor.run(DefaultEventExecutor.java:66) ~[netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: What's wrong with the question to be downvoted ?